# How can I do to aggregate count function return a number not an array

Tags: reactjs, mongoose

I try to count number of each article but the result is not what I want

This is my code

```
var nameWebsites = await Article.distinct("website.name");
        var idWebsites = await Article.distinct("website.id");
        var numberArticle = [];
        var result = [];

        for(var i = 0; i < nameWebsites.length; i++) {
            await Article.aggregate([
                { $match: {"website.id": idWebsites[i]}},
                { $count: "count"}        
            ], function(err, result){
                numberArticle.push(result);
            });
        }

        for(var i = 0; i < nameWebsites.length; i++) {
            result.push({"id":idWebsites[i], "name":nameWebsites[i], "number_article": numberArticle[i]});
        }
```

And this is a part of result

```
{"data":[{"id":1,"name":"Dan tri","number_article":[{"count":52952}]},...]}
```

I want the result like:

```
{"data":[{"id":1,"name":"Dân trí","number_article":52952},...]}
```

Comment: You can use var data = (your object array).data.length

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of grabbing the entire results of `numberArticle[i]`, get the just `count` of the first object in the array.

```
    for(var i = 0; i < nameWebsites.length; i++) {
        result.push({
            id: idWebsites[i], 
            name: nameWebsites[i], 
            number_article: numberArticle[i][0].count,
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var objectArray = {"data":[{"id":1,"name":"Dân trí","number_article":52952}]}
```

Then you can use

```js
objectArray.data.length
```